# Is it safe to compile and build source code on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it safe to compile and build source code on AWS instance ? Will there be any chance of copy or duplication of source code ?

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you to secure your EC2 instance. AWS gives you all the tools to lock it down as much or as little as you want. If you have the proper security setup, and don't leave holes, its about as secure as you can get.